# how can i shedule an event when there is a dst update in a timezone

Tags: time, dst

we have iot devices deployed on customer locations of different parts of the world. it should give some printed monitoring data in Daily weekly and monthly reports in our web dashboard. the issue is some timezones have day light savings, so these customers demand it should be based on dst.

what we want to try is

- get a list of timezones we use
- whenever there is a dst update in the timezone update the time on the device

but we can find how to fire an event for dst updates in different timezones, we can use python, ruby or shell or any command line tools that helps.

**UPDATE**
based on @rici 's answer i googled about zdump and found this

https://superuser.com/questions/805185/linux-command-to-check-wherever-this-day-is-a-dst-change-day-and-which-direction

this answer will give when DST starts and ends.
what i now do is manually set crontab based on these data.
how can i automate scheduling tasks?

Comment: What OS doesn't support DST natively?

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're asking, but I'd advise that you have all devices reckon time/date internally as UTC, and have them convert to local time only when they need to present data to the customer. Standard datetime library and excellent other libraries like dateutil should make this straightforward.

Comment: @jordanm it doesnt have an genaral os. it is an embedded device. but we can set time remotely.

Comment: Please explain in details by editing your question how the time system is working on the devices!

Comment: You're asking for too many things, and aren't clear enough on the details.  I'm voting to close as "too broad".  I suggest you break down this problem into separate parts and research each separately.  You'll likely find most of them have already been answered.

Comment: @MattJohnson i think this confusion is because i used ``python`` keyword. i removed the keyword and updated my progress in this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zdump` utility to print the current time in a liat of zones. If you do that every hour, and check the DST indicator against the previous output, you will see which zones have changed.

I have no idea how you can figure out which tmezones are important or how you identify which devices​ are in which time zone.

Comment: if needed i can create a lis of timezones with dst. we are currently serving only selected countries. timezone is  currently just a value stored in the device. so no issue in identifying it